# MessageUI in iOS 6.0 issue

Tags: objective-c, sms, message, xcode4.5

Beginner's question in Xcode and obj-c.

In my project I have a button with IBAction to send sms-messages without living my app (MessageUI linked to the project). At iOS 5 code worked well, but when I opened same project in latest Xcode to recompile it for iOS 6 I received warning: http://uaimage.com/image/10e31752
Is it something changed for using MessageUI in iOS 6?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I have experience the same problem since updating my iPhone 4 to IO6.  
No warnings though.  
It seems to be caused by a change in the threading model.

Comment: can we see the interface declaration?

Comment: Sure! http://uaimage.com/image/e71f051f  Protocol declaration outcommented because of warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this image:

http://uaimage.com/image/e71f051f

You have to use MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate and **not** MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Answer (score 1):

Well... something really weird just happened.

My project structure is as follows:

```
YourProject (Root of the project with Xcode Project Icon)
    /YourProject (Folder)
        /Group X (Nested Folder)
            /SomeViewController.h
        /Group Y (Nested Folder)
            /Group Y1 (Nested Folder)
                /OtherViewController.h
            /Group Y2 (Another Nested Folder)
                /YetAnotherViewController.h
```

The class SomeViewController, using MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate and MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate worked fine:

```
...
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {}
...
```

The classes OtherViewController and YetAnotherViewController, using the same MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate and MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate won't compile!

Errors were:

- Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate'

and/or

- Cannot find protocol declaration for 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'.

So I checked and re-checked imports, declared all the methods and my ViewControllers were the same, only differences were their names the data object.

At the end the solution was really silly! I solved this annoyance by moving the nested folders one level up. Everything compiles nicely!

Apparently the import of the libraries (when you add them to your project) does not reach files in Sub-Groups! I guess it is a bug with XCode and iOS 6, but I was getting the same errors.

Since the groups are virtual folders (they are not in the file system) just in the Project structure this is really weird.

I hope to save time and someone from a headache!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, hope it will helps someone too!

Answer (score 0):

Add `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` to your Header(.h) File.

Example: `UIViewController< MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>`

Comment: my ViewController is conforms to MFMessageComposeViewController, and MessageUI is added to the project folder. Everything worked fine in iOS 5 with the same code.